# Abiword opens a blank template on startup after upgrade

Tags: upgrade

A quick and annoying problem has come my way.

After I upgraded my Ubuntu from 14.10 to 15.04 I get a blank Abiword template/Abi document opened on login.

This open Abiword doc also applies to my other id's as well on my box when logged into.

Any idea how to stop this from happening?

I have verified that Abiword is not in my start-up list.

Thanks
Cheers

Comment: Do you use Abi word?

Answer (score 3):

It is a bug related to an Abiword collaboration plugin in telepathy (empathy). Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/abiword/+bug/1432271
A workaround is to delete the file /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Telepathy.Client.AbiCollab.service:

```
sudo rm /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Telepathy.Client.AbiCollab.service
```

Answer (score 1):

The client file providing the telepathy capabilities of Abiword collaboration plugin is missing from the debian package.
The file :

> /usr/share/telepathy/clients/AbiCollab.client

is missing from the debian package and its upstream version is available:

> https://github.com/AbiWord/abiword/blob/trunk/plugins/collab/backends/telepathy/unix/AbiCollab.client

PS: Abiword is spawned by mission-control-5 while it is collecting the capabilities of the telepathy clients. The above file acts like a cache thus avoid the need to start Abiword itself to get these.

I got the hint from  http://telepathy.freedesktop.org/wiki/Tubes/ :

> (To advertise support while the application is not running, it must be made service-activatable and install **a .client file**.)

Those findings I sent to the debian bug tracker this day :
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=794766#15 .

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could fix this was removing AbiWord.
After removal default Abi word doc doesn’t open on login. 
I need to do a reinstall to see if the issue comes back.

Update to follow